# how to use a pointer inside struct in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have a two struct, one is linked list.

```
typedef struct Mark{
       int  people;
       Node *nodeyy;
}Mark

typedef struct Node{
       struct node next;
       int value;
}Node
```

if i allocated memory for a node, let say

```
 Node *node1=malloc( sizeof(struct Node));
```

And I also allocated memory for a bookmark, let say

```
 Mark *mark1=malloc( sizeof(struct Mark));
```

I want to make the pointer nodeyy in the mark1 points to the same thing as node1, how can i do that?

I think that

```
 mark1->nodeyy=node1;
```

is definitely wrong.

Comment: Now that you have edited the code, why do you think mark1->nodeyy = node1 is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the int* in struct Mark to Node*

```
typedef struct Mark{
       int  people;
       Node *nodeyy;
}Mark
```

then you can do

```
mark -> nodeyy =  (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node))
```

Comment: i though mark-> nodeyy just a reference to  a node, why we need to allocate memory for a reference? What is the reason we can not just say mark->nodey=node1; ?

Comment: ya but mark->nodeyy is an int* in your code and it cannot hold the address of struct Node

Comment: sorry, typo , i mean Node *nodeyy;

Comment: we can say mark1->people=10, can we say mark1->nodeyy= node1; ? My question: is that the malloc steps necessary?

Comment: because node1 is just a type(just like primitive types int,float). you need to create variables of that type and make mark->nodeyy point to that variable.

Comment: if you have already created a variable for Node1, then you can do mark1->nodeyy=node1

Answer (score 1):

its correct now:

You will have to initialize the pointer or point it to an existing variable that you know won't go out-of-scope. BUT since node1 is dynamically allocated, you're just assigning one pointer to another, this creates a sort of reference to the newly allocated memory pointed by node1.

```
mark1->nodeyy = node1;
```

After this statement, mark1->nodeyy and node1 point to the memory location returned by the malloc(sizeof(Node)).

Comment: sorry, typo , i mean  Node *nodeyy;